# Interlacing addition of ordinals

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals, well-orders

Given ordinals $\alpha,\beta$, one definition of $\alpha+\beta$ is as the order type of the disjoint union $\alpha\sqcup\beta$ ordered with all the elements of $\alpha$ before the elements of $\beta$. But this looks like only one point on a spectrum of possible orders, where maybe you interlace $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the order. This motivates the following definition:

> Let $S:=S_{\alpha,\beta}$ be the collection of order types of well orders $\prec$ of $\alpha\sqcup\beta$ satisfying $x\prec y\leftrightarrow x<y$ for all $x,y\in\alpha$ and for all $x,y\in\beta$.

I would like to characterize this set. Some observations and partial results:

- Obviously $\alpha+\beta\in S$ and $\beta+\alpha\in S$, and furthermore $\alpha_1+\beta+\alpha_2\in S$ when $\alpha=\alpha_1+\alpha_2$, and similarly for other finite additive decompositions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
- What upper and lower bounds can we find on elements of $S$? If $\sigma\in S$, then $\max(\alpha,\beta)\le\sigma$ because both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ order-inject into $\sigma$. There is of course also the trivial upper bound $\sigma<|\alpha+\beta|^+$.
- The finite case $\alpha=m$, $\beta=n$ is trivial - $S=\{m+n\}$, but if $\alpha=n$ and $\beta$ is infinite then $S=[\beta,\beta+n]$, because we can "hide" some elements of $\alpha$ behind the first copy of $\omega$ in $\beta$ and put the rest after. But even proving $S\subseteq [\beta,\beta+n]$ in this simple case looks to be a bit tricky.
- The cofinality of $\sigma\in S$ is determined by the subsets $A\cup B=\sigma$ (where $A$ and $B$ are the disjoint copies of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\sigma$). If $\sup A<\sup B$, then $\operatorname{cf}\sigma=\operatorname{cf}\beta$. If $\sup A=\sup B$, then $\operatorname{cf}\alpha=\operatorname{cf}\beta=\operatorname{cf}\sigma$. Thus $\operatorname{cf}\sigma\in\{\operatorname{cf}\alpha,\operatorname{cf}\beta\}$ for all $\sigma\in S$.

Comment: I think you have to work on your definition of $S_{\alpha, \beta}$ (the requirement on $\prec$ most likely isn't what you want). In fact, $\prec$ isn't a total order to begin with since it doesn't compare elements of $\alpha$ with those of $\beta$.

Comment: @StefanMesken I think you're misunderstanding: $S_{\alpha,\beta}$ is a *set of well-orderings*, not a single well-ordering, on $\alpha\sqcup\beta$; the condition basically says that when you restrict a well-ordering in $S_{\alpha,\beta}$ to the $\alpha$ (resp. $\beta$) piece, you get the usual ordering of $\alpha$ (resp. $\beta$). I think Mario wrote exactly what he intended.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh, that's what that's supposed to mean. I disagree that this is what he wrote, though...

Comment: This set up is analogous to the shuffles used in algebraic topology when dealing with Eilenberg-Zilber maps. Of course they only concern finite sets, but maybe shuffles would be a good term to use here. The question would be, "what are the possible order types of shuffles of ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$?".

Comment: @StefanMesken Noah's interpretation is correct. I am being slightly loose in the definition by pretending that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are subsets of $\alpha\sqcup\beta$ - a more correct rendering would be something like $\iota_1(x)\prec\iota_1(y)\leftrightarrow x<y$ for $x,y\in\alpha$, and $\iota_2(x)\prec\iota_2(y)\leftrightarrow x<y$ for $x,y\in\beta$, where $\iota_1$ and $\iota_2$ are the canonical injections into the disjoint union.

Comment: @StefanMesken I think I just understood your first comment. It is true that the definition doesn't specify how the $\alpha$'s are to be compared to the $\beta$'s, and that's deliberate. An element of $S$ *is* a well order, because I said so, but there are a variety of ways to resolve the ambiguities, and that's where the action is.

Comment: Do you know about the Hessenberg / natural sum of ordinals?

Comment: @nombre I wasn't (more precisely I read about it a long time ago and forgot), and it does appear to be intimately connected with this definition, since Wikipedia literally defines $\alpha\#\beta=\sup S$. This is great since it shows that $S$ has a maximum element, and gives a formula for it too.

Comment: Put some brackets in the def'n of $\prec$. Because "$A$ iff $B$ if $C$ or $D$" is ambiguous, and the reader has to read the next paragraph to solve the puzzle of what it is meant to say.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Better? Note that I've also rerendered the definition in the comment above.

Comment: Yes, Now it's clear................

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to deal with this problem is to look at the decompositions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in terms of indecomposables (i.e., powers of $\omega$), that is, we consider the Cantor normal form of both ordinals.

For example, consider $\omega^3+\omega+2$ and $\omega^2+5$. The only well-orderings you can form from them are $\omega^3+\omega+n$ for $n=2,\dots,7$, $\omega^3+\omega^2+\omega+n$ for $n=2,\dots,7$, and $\omega^3+\omega^2+m$ for $m=5,6,7$.

The point is that an ordinal $\gamma$ being a power of $\omega$ is equivalent to the fact that if $\gamma=\delta+\epsilon$, then $\epsilon=0$ or $\gamma$. In the well-orderings you are considering, you are splitting each indecomposable $\gamma$ mentioned in the Cantor normal forms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as a sum, and interleaving the pieces.

This problem has been considered before. The key reference is

> [MR0065907 (16,502a)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=65907). Toulmin, G. H. *[Shuffling ordinals and transfinite dimension](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/plms/s3-4.1.177/full)*. Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) **4**, (1954). 177–195.

Toulmin says that an ordinal $\gamma$ is a *shuffle* of two ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ if and only if $\gamma$ can be written as a disjoint union $\gamma=A\cup B$ where $A$ has order type $\alpha$ and $B$ has order type $\beta$. This is precisely what you call an interlacing sum.

Among others, he proves that the number of ordinals that are shuffles of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is finite (see Theorem 1.38 in Toulmin's paper, that completely describes all ordinals in $S_{\alpha,\beta}$).

The largest shuffle is the Hessenberg natural sum (which is commutative), where the indecomposable terms in the Cantor sums of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are organized in decreasing order: Say that 
$$\alpha=\omega^{a_1}n_1+\dots+\omega^{a_k}n_k$$ and $$\beta=\omega^{a_1}m_1+\dots+\omega^{a_k}m_k,$$
where $a_1>a_2>\dots>a_k$ are ordinals and the $n_i$ and $m_i$ are natural numbers (possibly zero). Using this notation, the Hessenberg sum of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is $$\alpha\#\beta=\omega^{a_1}(n_1+m_1)+\dots+\omega^{a_k}(n_k+m_k).$$
The smallest shuffle can be described as follows: Let $\alpha=\alpha_1+\alpha_2$ where $\alpha_1$ is zero or a limit ordinal and $\alpha_2$ is finite, and define $\beta=\beta_1+\beta_2$ analogously. Then the smallest shuffle of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (the lower sum, in Toulmin's terminology), is

- $\alpha$, if $\alpha_1>\beta_1$,
- $\alpha+\beta_2=\beta+\alpha_2$, if $\alpha_1=\beta_1$, and
- $\beta$, if $\alpha_1<\beta_1$.

There is an earlier reference dealing with a related, but different problem:

> [MR0005878 (3,225a)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=5878). Carruth, Philip W. *[Arithmetic of ordinals with applications to the theory of ordered Abelian groups](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1942-48-04/S0002-9904-1942-07649-X/home.html)*. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. **48**, (1942), 262–271.

Carruth focuses on what he calls *natural sums* (Lipparini refers to them as "mixed sums", to avoid confusion with the Hessenberg sum, that is usually also called *the* natural sum). He describes natural sums axiomatically: A binary operation $\oplus$ on ordinals is a natural sum if and only if it satisfies the following properties:

1. $\oplus$ is commutative and associative.
2. For any $\alpha$, $\alpha\oplus 0=\alpha$.
3. For any ordinals $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$, we have that $\alpha<\beta$ if and only if $\alpha\oplus\gamma<\beta\oplus\gamma$.

He proceeds to prove that the smallest natural sum is the Hessenberg sum, and along the way also shows that the Hessenberg sum is the largest shuffle.

---

(Actually, it was useful to see this question, since it helped me sort out what Carruth's paper does. I learned of it through another paper which suggested Carruth's paper only dealt with shuffles.)

Comment: Great answer. There is one claim in here that I think is false, though: If $\alpha=\beta=\omega$, then $S=\{\omega,\omega+\omega\}$, so it is not true that the smallest mixed sum is one of $\alpha+\beta,\beta+\alpha$.

Comment: Ah, you are right, my apologies. I misread the paper (and only considered messy examples). Let me recheck and I'll make the appropriate edit.

Comment: @Mario Many thanks for asking this. I looked carefully at  Carruth's paper and fixed my confusion.